# Android Studio Flutter hot-reload and hot-restart buttons disabled and stuck at "Installing and launching" on a real iOS device

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm still new to Flutter and programming. Please be kind. Thank you.

This never happen before. I mean the hot reload and hot restart always works. But this time something strange happen:
The app loads on a real iOS device and all works perfectly there. But Android Studio console shows "Installing and launching" with no end. The print statements doesn't show up. The hot reload and hot restart buttons are disabled as well as the green play button at the top. And when I press the stop button (the red square button) the console shows that its stopped but the app still running on the device.

My device is iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 13.3.1

For the iOS Simulators, the hot reload and hot restart works fine. I don't know if this is related but the slider thumb doesn't move in a simulator but it moves in real iOS device.

Here is my flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.13.7, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.13.7 at /Applications/flutter
    • Framework revision a3bbdfb23a (3 months ago), 2020-01-03 16:19:11 -0500
    • Engine revision eb139936eb
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.0.0 2f57602411)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Applications/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Applications/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.42.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone        • b3ebbe93864b12b2d78acd5efecf25da9ac75d28 • ios            • iOS 13.3.1
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • AAFD9B5B-5E10-40AB-A9D8-75D9DAD5EB3D     • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-2 (simulator)
    • Chrome            • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.163
    • Web Server        • web-server                               • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

• No issues found!
```

Thank you so much!!! Any help is appreciated!!